# Outlier Analysis Python: Is there a better/more efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I am trying to do my outlier analysis in Python. Since I have multiple dataframes with varying length, I want to deduct 2.5% of both the tail and head when the dataframe has 10 observations, 0.25% when it has 100 etc. Currently, I have some code that seems to work. However, I still have the feeling it could be a little bit more efficient. This is mainly because of the last 2 lines. I feel like the filter could be done in one line. Also, I am unsure if the .loc is of good use here. Perhaps there is a better way to do this? Does anyone have suggestions?

This is my first question, so please let me know if there is anything I can improve with my question =)

Currently, this is my code:

```
    df_filtered_3['variable'] = df_filtered_3['variable1'] / df_filtered_3['variable2']

    if len(df_filtered_3.index) <= 10:
        low = .025
        high = .0975
    elif len(df_filtered_3.index) <= 100:
        low = .0025
        high = .00975
    elif len(df_filtered_3.index) <= 1000:
        low = .00025
        high = .000975
    elif len(df_filtered_3.index) <= 10000:
        low = .000025
        high = .0000975
    else:
        low = .0000025
        high = .00000975

    quant_df = df_filtered_3.quantile([low, high])
    df_filtered_3 = df_filtered_3.loc[df_filtered_3['variable'] > int(quant_df.loc[low, 'variable']), :]
    df_filtered_3 = df_filtered_3.loc[df_filtered_3['variable'] < int(quant_df.loc[high, 'variable']), :]
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? Make sure to highlight the whole selection and press ctrl-k

Comment: Thanks for changing this for me! I appreciate it.

Comment: "I still have the feeling it could be a little bit more efficient" - what makes you feel like that ? is it performing badly? if so - any idea where's the bottleneck ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have clarified that. I just edited the question.

Comment: Can you post a small sample data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it shorter, but not necessarily faster:

```
In [57]: coefs = np.array([.025, .0975])

In [58]: coefs / pd.cut([len(df.index)], [0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, np.inf], labels=[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000], right=True)[0]
Out[58]: array([ 0.025 ,  0.0975])
```

Examples:

```
In [59]: coefs / pd.cut([105], [0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, np.inf], labels=[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000], right=True)[0]
Out[59]: array([ 0.00025 ,  0.000975])

In [60]: coefs / pd.cut([1005], [0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, np.inf], labels=[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000], right=True)[0]
Out[60]: array([  2.50000000e-05,   9.75000000e-05])
```

Comment: @jezrael, thank you! OP is testing a single number (`len(df_filtered_3.index)`), so the `if ... else ...` block might be faster in this case

Comment: Hmmm, it mainly depends of data ... But generally it should be faster  in my opinion

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall give it a try!